# FreeRADIUS 3.0.11 ignoring Access-Request from one NIC interface

Tags: networking, ubuntu, iptables, network-adapter, freeradius

I've installed FreeRADIUS 3.0.11 to Ubuntu Server 16.04. The Ubuntu Server runs on a ESXi virtual machine. The virtual machine has two NICs. One is for connecting to an admin network, the other one is for customer LAN. I'm also using a PfSense virtual machine as a firewall between LAN and Ubuntu server.

[A picture of my network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u59Ae.png)

The problem is that when I'm testing from **admin network** `radtest test 1234 192.168.1.144 1812 testing123` the FreeRADIUS server notices and answers properly, but when I'm testing from **LAN**, the FreeRADIUS server doesn't get the Access-Request at all. I'm using the server in debugging mode `freeradius -X`.

The IPs are:

```
Ubuntu server admin NIC, ens160: 192.168.1.144
Ubuntu server NIC to PfSense, ens192: 192.168.34.2
PfSense NIC to Ubuntu server: 192.168.34.1
PfSense LAN NIC: 192.168.33.1
```

I've checked with **tcpdump** that the Ubuntu server is receiving the Access-Request packages. The IP 192.168.33.50 is a laptop's IP.

```
sudo tcpdump -i ens192 port 1812
10:24:18.578802 IP 192.168.33.50.63334 > 192.168.34.2.radius: RADIUS, Access-Request (1), id: 0x09 length: 44
10:24:19.578202 IP 192.168.33.50.63334 > 192.168.34.2.radius: RADIUS, Access-Request (1), id: 0x09 length: 44
```

I'm using **iptables** for forwarding HTTP and HTTPS to the PfSense virtual machine, so I can configure it from admin network.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed May  4 10:23:08 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:396]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:396]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3:213]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3:213]
-A PREROUTING -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4954 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.34.1:80
-A PREROUTING -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4955 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.34.1:443
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.34.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.34.2
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.34.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.34.2
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  4 10:23:08 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Wed May  4 10:23:08 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [24:2294]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [16:3245]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp -m multiport --dports 1812 -m comment --comment     "Accept RADIUS" -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed May  4 10:23:08 2016
```

I've checked that FreeRADIUS is listening port 1812.

```
netstat -lun | grep 1812
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18120         0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1812            0.0.0.0:*
udp6       0      0 :::1812                 :::*
```

I tried forwarding the port 1812 from interface to another, but either I configured it wrong or it didn't help. I'm pretty sure there is some easy trick to get this working, but I haven't found it yet. Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE**

I tried to put **Requests logging** on by uncommenting line `requests = ${logdir}/radiusd-%{%{Virtual-Server}:-DEFAULT}-%Y%m%d.log` in file `/etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf`. However this raises an error and freeradius doesn't start at all. Debugging mode starts but it doesn't write anything to radius.log file.

```
sudo freeradius
radiusd: Error: Failed to parse log{} section.
```

It seems that the Requests logging isn't working since version 3.0.9. Source: github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/issues/1131

Comment: Have you checked the main server logs to make sure the server is seeing the packet coming in with a recognised source address?

Comment: What do you mean by "main server logs"?

Comment: The RADIUS daemon's main log.  As configured in ``/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf``

Comment: FreeRADIUS can have N different log destinations, but global server events always go to the main log.

Comment: @Eastman, Please, post your solution as answer. You can (and should) answer you own question.

Comment: Okay, I posted the solution as an answer. Somehow I remembered that one shouldn't answer their own questions.

@ArranCudbard-Bell, thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had to add a gateway to the other NIC also.

Here's my initial `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
#auto ens160
#iface ens160 inet6 auto

# ESXi NIC admin network
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
address 192.168.1.144
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2

# ESXi NIC DMZ
auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
address 192.168.34.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I added a second routing table (the last line is added):

```
sudo vim /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
1 rt2
```

Configured the new routing table:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.34.0/24 dev ens192 src 192.168.34.2 table rt2
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.34.1 dev ens192 table rt2
```

Added routing rules:

```
sudo ip rule add from 192.168.34.2/32 table rt2
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.34.2/32 table rt2
```

Tested that the configuration works and made it permanent by modifying the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
iface ens192 inet static
    address 192.168.34.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    post-up ip route add 192.168.34.0/24 dev ens192 src 192.168.34.2 table rt2
    post-up ip route add default via 192.168.34.1 dev ens192 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add from 192.168.34.2/32 table rt2
    post-up ip rule add to 192.168.34.2/32 table rt2
```

The source for the solution: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System

**IPTABLES**

And to keep my port forwarding running, I got to add **outgoing interface** to iptables rules (-o ens192 added):

```
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.34.1/32 -o ens192 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.34.2
-A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.34.1/32 -o ens192 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.34.2
```